C# string extension methods with same name based on syntax
I would like to compare 2 strings, with syntax either ^([A-Z]\d{2}![A-Z]{2}\d|[A-Z]{3})$ or ^\d{3}$ respectively for both strings with 2 different extension methods but with an identical name IsHigher(this string source, string target).
It seems possible to use the same method name since they are defined in 2 different static classes VersionsExtensions and IssuesExtensions to separate the logic (I don't want to determine the appropriate comparison inside the method, but rather to determine it externally and implicitly). Therefore, is it possible to "redirect" at run-time to the proper method based on the string syntax via an attribute such as [RequiresSyntax(...)] to constrain the string for example?
"A00".IsLower("B00");
"001".IsLower("002"); // I still want to keep them as string instead of number.

Edit :
public static IsHigher(this string source, string target)
{
    var regex = new Regex("^([A-Z]\d{2}![A-Z]{2}\d|[A-Z]{3})$");

    if (regex.IsMatch(source) && regex.IsMatch(target))
    {
        return Version.IsLower(source, target); // Static specific method.
    }

    regex = new Regex("^\d{3}$");

    if (regex.IsMatch(source) && regex.IsMatch(target))
    {
        return Issue.IsLower(source, target);
    }
    
    throw new Exception(
$"Unable to compare \"{target}\" with \"{source}\"!");
}


What's wrong with matching the string against the regexes inside IsLower and do different things depending on the result? Why do you want to avoid that?

Normally, you'd get an ambiguous method error if you do that; however, there is a way to do it - but it would involve writing and deploying a Roslyn code generator that uses the "interceptors" language feature. How much do you care about this? Is this "meh, if it is simple", or is it "I absolutely need this or my world will crumble"? Because that's a lot of effort...

Side note: in most useful cases, at least one operand is non-constant; how would you have the compiler choose anything in that case? Maybe just test all patterns inside the single method, for consistency

Alright, not worse making it more complicated. Il will determine the logic inside the extension method with "qualified" heper methods (see edited answer) to allow future imlrmentations.
